# R.id.home value in R.java does not match documentation

Tags: android

I'm using Android studio and am trying to get the action bar 'home as up' working.
After I've enabled it via actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);, and I press the action bar 'back' button, onOptionItemSelected gets called ok, and getItemId returns 0x0102002c (this matches the documentation). But when I look at R.java, I see that R.id.home is defined to be 0x7f070017. Hence when I check for the item ID to match R.id.home, it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you defined your own R.id.home? You should use the android.R.id.home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Egor is correct.

The documentation [says](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#up) to use `android.R.id.home`

**not** `R.id.home`

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. 'R.id.home' points to a declaration in a v7 compat file: R.java. 'android.R.id.home' is declared in ids.xml in the SDK.